# How to get units for revit model using Forge model derivative APIs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am looking for a way to figure out units for a Revit model on Autodesk Forge cloud, needed for my backend application.
I checked model derivative endpoints but not able to find any idea.
Is there a way to get units for a Revit model using Forge Model Derivative APIs or other APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think that bit of data is serialized in the meta data SVF pack file and might only be available through Viewer.

I am checking with Engineering to double confirm if that's the case and will come back to update this answer once I hear back.

**EDIT:**

Engineering just confirmed that info is currently not present through the API endpoints but I've let them know that's highly desired so hopefully they will make that happen in the near future.

Alternatively in the meantime they suggest that you can try the property DB  which is basically flat SQLite and find the meta data there - download it via [urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET) and can find its URN via the [manifest endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) and it should look like:

```
 {
                    "guid": "cb73c076-d3cd-a725-754f-a64cd8c07648",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2JzYjIzMzMzMy9zYmFoYWhhLmR3Zw/output/properties.db",
                    "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                    "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                    "status": "success"
                },
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I can access units from property DB. But I think I cannot auotmate this in my application since dependency on SQLite. I would really appreciate if the endpoint is open to use as sooner as possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can consider serializing the SQLite into your own data source - see a list of conversion tools available [here](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)

Comment: Hey @Bryan, I am chacking a property db, Its getting very difficult for mapping between attributes, ids and values. E,g If I want units for Length and they have different data_type_context. Refer this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lc0Somt_SNBRtTjCOKrdaif8gRAnOKBS/view?usp=sharing  . Do you have any idea which one should be considered for lets say Length?